# Inserting data into SQL database dynamically with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, mysql-python

I've been trying to input data into a database from some Python lists doing this:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = db.cursor()
a = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
b = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
c.execute("INSERT INTO table_name(?) VALUES (?)", (tuple(a), tuple(b)))
db.commit
```

However I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 95, in <module>
    c.execute("INSERT INTO table_name(?) VALUES (?)", (tuple(a), tuple(b)))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

I've tried simplifying things and taking out a single item from the list at a time using a loop and only adding those, but that didn't work either. In fact, I get the same exact error if I try passing in a single variable (say:

```
a = "col1"
b = "val1"
c.execute("INSERT INTO table_name(?) VALUES (?)", (a, b))
```

Despite this, when I try manually passing in column names and variable names the database updated without any issues. What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot use placeholders that prevent the SQL parser from preparing a query plan. The table name cannot be a placeholder.

Comment: It isn't, I'm using table_name here but in my code I've got the name of the actual table (sorry thought this would make it easier but apparently not) - the placeholders are just for the columns and values

Comment: Oh. Is there any way to specify which column a value goes to? The data I'll have won't necessarily be ordered the same as the table so I can't just dump it all in...

Comment: If I build it dynamically though doesn't that run into issues if there are special characters in the variables being passed through? Thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: No. Only build the _colum name_ dynamically, but keep the placeholders for the values.

Comment: Aaah of course! Thanks, happy to mark it as correct if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use placeholders that prevent the SQL parser from preparing a query plan. This means that neither the table name nor the column can be a placeholder.

When inserting, you can either always insert all values using placeholders. Then you need to pad your insert tuple with the appropriate amount of `None` for the missing values:

```
b = [None, "value2", None]
c.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (foo, bar, baz) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (tuple(values)))
```

Alternatively, you can build the colum name dynamically, but keep the placeholders for the values:

```
column_names = ["foo", "bar"].join(",")
placeholders = ["?","?"].join( "," )
statement = "INSERT INTO table_name (" + column_names + ") VALUES ("+placeholders+")" 
c.execute(statement)
```

As long as you make sure that the user is not allowed to specify the column names or as long as you verify them through a dictionary, you can use this approach.